# Every $t$-coloring of $K_{2t+1}$ contains a monochromatic cycle

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, coloring

I need help in the following question:

> I need to prove that in all possible coloring with $t$ colors of the complete graph $K$ with $2t+1$ vertices, there will always be a monochromatic cycle (its size doesn't matter).

I tried with induction on number of colors ($t$) but got nowhere.

Any help would be welcome. :)

Thanks!

Comment: By circle do you mean cycle? One of the colors appears three times, so you have a monochromatic triangle even.

Comment: Daniel: I replaced the word "circle" by "cycle" everywhere since that seemed to be the intended term. Hope it's ok,

Comment: yea it was, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the probabilistic method.

The number of edges in $K_{2t+1}$ is $\frac{2t(2t+1)}{2} = t(2t+1)$, so the average number of edges in a color class is $2t+1$. Hence there exists a monochromatic subgraph with at least $2t+1$ edges; this subgraph necessarily contains a cycle. Done!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Seems so easy now :)